# kafka sink connector. How insert record_key to table if record_value = null?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a topic where the data is only record_key and the record_value is null. I need to write the fields from the record_key to the table through the sink connector, but I get an error. How do I insert values from a record_key, ignoring record_value = null?

```
{
  "name": "ObjectForDelete.sink",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "transforms": [
    "uuid",
    "name"
  ],
  "topics": [
    "ObjectForDeletePG"
  ],
  "transforms.uuid.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Key",
  "transforms.uuid.topic.field": "key.uuid",
  "transforms.name.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Key",
  "transforms.name.topic.field": "key.name",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/ulk",
  "connection.user": "root",
  "connection.password": "****",
  "dialect.name": "PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect",
  "insert.mode": "insert",
  "table.name.format": "ObjectForDelete",
  "pk.mode": "none",
  "pk.fields": [],
  "db.timezone": "Europe/Kiev"
}
```

ERROR:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Sink connector 'ObjectForDelete.sink' is configured with 'delete.enabled=false' and 'pk.mode=kafka' and therefore requires records with a non-null Struct value and non-null Struct schema, but found record at (topic='ObjectForDeletePG',partition=0,offset=0,timestamp=1623758581060) with a null value and null value schema.
```

Comment: As the error says, it wont allow null valued records when `configured with 'delete.enabled=false' and 'pk.mode=kafka'`. Null values are treated as deletes, not inserts/updates. If you want to write those fields, move the key to the value part of the record

Comment: Can this be done with kafka connect? There is a valueToKey transformation, but there is no reverse conversion.

Comment: `ExtractField` can be used since your values are null anyway